# How to properly express conditional causal relationship

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals, causative-have

Is this correct and normal way to express causation relationship?:

> {Something} would not be required, had {something_other} been done properly.

Or maybe this form is more natural?:

> If {something_other} was done properly, {something} would not be required.

Comment: I didn't want to edit your question without asking. Do you mean "causal" not "casual"? "Casual" means informal. A "casual relationship" might be construed as one of a sexual nature between uncommitted people, see: "casual dating"

Comment: @TecBrat, yes, you're right, thank you! I'll correct the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these both work:

(If/Had) the sink had been repaired correctly, we wouldn't need to replace the floor.

We wouldn't need to replace the floor (if/had) the sink had been repaired correctly.